How to fetch records from multiple collections in MongoDB?
How to fetch data from multiple collections in MongoDB using a single query. I have 4 collections in which I want to fetch all active status records with limit 20
Below is my query sample
db.seasons.aggregate([
 { "$facet": {
"c1": [
  { "$lookup": {
    "from": "episodes",
    "pipeline": [
      { "$match": { "status": 1 } }
    ],
    "as": "collection1"
  }}
],
"c2": [
  { "$lookup": {
    "from": "movies",
    "pipeline": [
      { "$match": { "status": 1 } }
    ],
    "as": "collection2"
  }}
],
"c3": [
  { "$lookup": {
    "from": "shows",
    "pipeline": [
      { "$match": { "status": 1 } }
    ],
    "as": "collection3"
  }}
]
 }},
 { "$project": {
    "data": {
    "$concatArrays": [ "$c1", "$c2", "$c3" ]
  }
}},
  { "$unwind": "$data" },
  { "$replaceRoot": { "newRoot": "$data" } },
  { $limit : 20 },
  {$sort: {"createdAt": -1}}
])

I am getting error as : MongoServerError[Location4568]: PlanExecutor error during aggregation :: caused by :: Total size of documents in episodes matching pipeline's $lookup stage exceeds 104857600 bytes

Seems like you need to limit the episodes' document returned in the $lookup pipeline

@YongShun can you please add answer in comments

$facet can't spill to disk so you are limited to 100MB in the resulting documents. You are clearly exceeding that. Can you share in simple terms what you are trying to achieve as there may be a better option. Other aggregation stages can spill to disk with allowDiskUse.

@jQueeny simple I just want to query on above 4 collection and want to display only 20 records

Sorry, yes I just read that. You have already explained it simple enough.

In the c1 pipeline, you can add sorting by field and then limit the documents, "pipeline": [ { "$match": { "status": 1 } },  { $sort: { createdAt: 1 } }, { $limit: 20 } ]

@YongShun 's comment is really an answer. A comment would be something like - I would run 4 separate queries from the app, and sort-limit them in the app itself.
